# Check if element exists, and do .. if not

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify an element and check whether it exists or not. I've tried many codes and I all got errors. I've tried this with "if driver.find ..." but I got errors. Any way to verify an element without errors? I used selenium.

I have tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        print ("Alert")
        raw_input("")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ("Nothing")
        raw_input("")
```

And I've got this:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>>> from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
>>>
>>> def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
...     try:
...         webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
... print ("Alert")
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print ("Alert")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
>>> raw_input("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
>>>     except NoSuchElementException:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>         print ("Nothing")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print ("Nothing")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> raw_input("")
```

Comment: You are missing the `except` part of a try-except block: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions
You have your print aligned in the upper code but not in the shell

Comment: There is "except" in the code. Why do you exactly

Comment: It should be `driver.find_element_by_xpath`, not `webdriver.find_element_by_xpath`

Comment: the same result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by checking the `size` of the `list` of the `WebElements`, if the size is greater than 0 that means the element is present on the page else it is not present.
Your code should be like:

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']"))>0:
    # Element is present
    print("Alert")
else:
    # Element is not present
    print ("Nothing")
```

Comment: raw_input("")^SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @PrsFathollahi I copied the `raw_input("")` line from your code. Did you call a method on that line or what ? You can remove that line and the code would work fine

Comment: @PrsFathollahi didnt get you ?

Comment: Let me try_____

Comment: you mean no raw_input("") at all. I mean in your answer you wrote one raw_input("").

Comment: @PrsFathollahi i have updated my answer, please try the latest code

Comment: sorry. I got this:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Comment: @PrsFathollahi have updated my ans again, please try the updated code

Comment: can you answer this, please? :

Comment: This is all clearly nothing to do with the problem actually reported in the question.